# How to get the session statistics from JMX?

Tags: jmx, mbeans

Are there any Pre-built MBeans available for session statistics(Maximum Sessions, Available Sessions etc) in JMX ?

If not , please guide me to the right approach to get the session statistics from remote server.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: JMX is just a way to exposing beans externally.  Consult your server documentation to see what the server choose to expose.

Comment: Thanks for the response . Do we need to set any property in server configuration file to expose the session statistics ?

Comment: Not if you can attach with visualvm (and the mbeans plugin) or jconsole on the same host.  Otherwise you will need to follow the JMX tutorials.